# Where is bruriah mentioned?

Tags: talmud-gemara

Can you please list all the places where bruriah is mentioned and of quoted? I have found some, but not all.
Thank you.

Comment: One of them is this very Web page. (That should give you a glimpse of how this question is too broad.) When you [edit] to narrow the question down, you might also specify whether you mean Bruriah the school, Bruriah the wife of _Rabi Meir Baal Hanes_, or Bruriah your sister. Thanks for bringing your question to Mi Yodeya! I recommend you take the site [tour] for more on how it works. In particular, questions need to be answerable (and answers need to answer the questions).

Comment: @msh210 Based on the tag, I assume the question was meant to be limited to the Talmud(s) and/or classical Jewish literature...

Comment: @Loewian, instead of our assuming what the asker's intent is (and even your assumption is not definite: maybe the Talmud, maybe the Talmuds, maybe classical Jewish literature) and possibly answering something that he or she is not looking for, he or she can just clarify the question and get the answers that he or she desires.

Comment: Berakhot 10a; Eruvin 53b-54a; Pesahim 62b; Avoda Zara 18a-b; Tosefta Kelim, Bava Metzia 1:6; Yalkut Shimoni, Yeshayahu 477.